# .Net-Core How to add external dll transitive reference to class libaries

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core

I have a solution with 2 class libraries, one for `models` and one for `services`, another external project dll (`FooSharedClasses.dll`):

[image]

The intent of of this `FooSharedClasses` is only for modeling (zero code logic - only classes and properties for easier naming api connection), So naturally I've only added it as a reference to my `Models` class library.

The `Services` class library has a reference to the `Models` class library, so I assumed that the `FooSharedClasses` will be available to `Service`.

The only way I could manage the `FooSharedClasses` to be available as a reference to `Service` is to added manually (by add reference).

**Is there another way for only add the `FooSharedClasses` only ones to the `Model` class library so it would be also available to `Services` class library?**

Comment: I'm afraid no, because transitive reference is only for project references and not dll references. If you want to do so, reference the sharedclasses project in models project, instead of referencing the dll.

Comment: @Siavash Thanks but I have access only to the dll (its not my project)

Comment: then i would reference dll from both projects. this is the way sadly :)